# Redis Booksleeve client, ResultCompletionMode.PreserveOrder not working

Tags: c#, redis, booksleeve

When I print out received messages on the Console the displayed messages are all messed up, each message containing 5 string sub-messages that are printed on the Console before control reverts back to  the incoming message callback. I strongly assume this is because the incoming message event is raised async in Booksleeve?

I refer to the following post, [How does PubSub work in BookSleeve/ Redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862534/how-does-pubsub-work-in-booksleeve-redis),  where the author, Marc Gravell, pointed to the ability to force sync reception by setting Completion Mode to "PreserveOrder". I have done that, tried before and after connecting the client. Neither seems to work.

Any ideas how I can receive messages and print them on the console in the exact order they were sent? I only have one single publisher in this case.

Thanks

**Edit:**

Below some code snippets to show how I send messages and the Booksleeve wrapper I quickly wrote.

Here the client (I have a similar `Client2` that receives the messages and checks order, but I omitted it as it seems trivial).

```
class Client1
{
    const string ClientId = "Client1";
    private static Messaging Client { get; set; }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var settings = new MessagingSettings("127.0.0.1", 6379, -1, 60, 5000, 1000);
        Client = new Messaging(ClientId, settings, ReceiveMessage);
        Client.Connect();

        Console.WriteLine("Press key to start sending messages...");
        Console.ReadLine();

        for (int index = 1; index <= 100; index++)
        {
            //I turned this off because I want to preserve 
            //the order even if messages are sent in rapit succession

            //Thread.Sleep(5); 

            var msg = new MessageEnvelope("Client1", "Client2", index.ToString());
            Client.SendOneWayMessage(msg);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press key to exit....");
        Console.ReadLine();

        Client.Disconnect();
    }

    private static void ReceiveMessage(MessageEnvelope msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Message Received");
    }
}
```

Here the relevant code snippets of the library:

```
public void Connect()
    {
        RequestForReplyMessageIds = new ConcurrentBag<string>();

        Connection = new RedisConnection(Settings.HostName, Settings.Port, Settings.IoTimeOut);
        Connection.Closed += OnConnectionClosed;
        Connection.CompletionMode = ResultCompletionMode.PreserveOrder;
        Connection.SetKeepAlive(Settings.PingAliveSeconds);

        try
        {
            if (Connection.Open().Wait(Settings.RequestTimeOutMilliseconds))
            {
                //Subscribe to own ClientId Channel ID
                SubscribeToChannel(ClientId);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Could not connect Redis client to server");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not connect Redis Client to Server");
        }
    }

public void SendOneWayMessage(MessageEnvelope message)
    {
        SendMessage(message);
    }

private void SendMessage(MessageEnvelope msg)
    {
        //Connection.Publish(msg.To, msg.GetByteArray());
        Connection.Publish(msg.To, msg.GetByteArray()).Wait();
    }

private void IncomingChannelSubscriptionMessage(string channel, byte[] body)
    {
        var msg = MessageEnvelope.GetMessageEnvelope(body);

        //forward received message
        ReceivedMessageCallback(msg);

        //release requestMessage if returned msgId matches
        string msgId = msg.MessageId;
        if (RequestForReplyMessageIds.Contains(msgId))
        {
            RequestForReplyMessageIds.TryTake(out msgId);
        }
    }

public void SubscribeToChannel(string channelName)
    {
        if (!ChannelSubscriptions.Contains(channelName))
        {
            var subscriberChannel = Connection.GetOpenSubscriberChannel();
            subscriberChannel.Subscribe(channelName, IncomingChannelSubscriptionMessage).Wait();
            ChannelSubscriptions.Add(channelName);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing *exactly* how you are checking for this, it is hard to comment, but what I *can* say is that any threading oddity is going to be hard to track down and fix, and is therefore very unlikely to be addressed in BookSleeve, [given that it has been succeeded](http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/so-i-went-and-wrote-another-redis-client.html). However! It will *absolutely* be checked in StackExchange.Redis. Here's the a rig I've put together in SE.Redis (and, embarrassingly, it did highlight a slight bug, fixed in next release, so .222 or later); output first:

```
Subscribing...

Sending (preserved order)...
Allowing time for delivery etc...
Checking...
Received: 500 in 2993ms
Out of order: 0

Sending (any order)...
Allowing time for delivery etc...
Checking...
Received: 500 in 341ms
Out of order: 306
```

(keep in mind that 500 x 5ms is 2500, so we should not be amazed by the 2993ms number, or the 341ms - this is mainly the cost of the `Thread.Sleep` we have added to nudge the thread-pool into overlapping them; if we remove that, both loops take 0ms, which is awesome - but we can't see the overlapping issue so convincingly)

As you can see, the first run has the correct order output; the second run has mixed order, but it **ten times faster**. And that is when doing trivial work; for *real* work it would be even more noticeable. As always, it is a trade-off.

Here's the test rig:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using StackExchange.Redis;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var conn = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost"))
        {
            var sub = conn.GetSubscriber();
            var received = new List<int>();
            Console.WriteLine("Subscribing...");
            const int COUNT = 500;
            sub.Subscribe("foo", (channel, message) =>
            {
                lock (received)
                {
                    received.Add((int)message);
                    if (received.Count == COUNT)
                        Monitor.PulseAll(received); // wake the test rig
                }
                Thread.Sleep(5); // you kinda need to be slow, otherwise
                // the pool will end up doing everything on one thread
            });
            SendAndCheck(conn, received, COUNT, true);
            SendAndCheck(conn, received, COUNT, false);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static void SendAndCheck(ConnectionMultiplexer conn, List<int> received, int quantity, bool preserveAsyncOrder)
    {
        conn.PreserveAsyncOrder = preserveAsyncOrder;
        var sub = conn.GetSubscriber();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Sending ({0})...", (preserveAsyncOrder ? "preserved order" : "any order"));
        lock (received)
        {
            received.Clear();
            // we'll also use received as a wait-detection mechanism; sneaky

            // note: this does not do any cheating;
            // it all goes to the server and back
            for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
            {
                sub.Publish("foo", i);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Allowing time for delivery etc...");
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            if (!Monitor.Wait(received, 10000))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Timed out; expect less data");
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Checking...");
            lock (received)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Received: {0} in {1}ms", received.Count, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                int wrongOrder = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(quantity, received.Count); i++)
                {
                    if (received[i] != i) wrongOrder++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Out of order: " + wrongOrder);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still a bit confused by some of your comments and code: So, if I just fire 100 messages in a tight loop without slowing Thread.Sleep or the like the order would not be preserved? This is exactly what I am seeing and I wonder how I can force order preservation

Comment: @Matt no that isn't what I am saying at all. The Sleep exists only to exacerbate the situation. To make it work as you want, just set PreserveAsyncOrder to true. Actually it defaults to true anyway!

Comment: I edited my question and pasted all relevant code. Could you please take a look what I may be doing wrong that prevents receiving the messages in the order sent? Please note that in the method `SendMessage(MessageEnvelope msg)` I purposely went the synchronous route. Is that necessary to preserve the order? My understanding, according to your explanations earlier, is that with `PreserveOrder` turned I can send messages async and the order is still preserved. In any case it does not work either way.

Comment: I just noticed we apparently talk about two different libraries here. I am talking about the Booksleeve standalone library (version 1.3.41.0) which I got from Nuget. Do you recommend to use the StackExchange.Redis one?

Comment: I made some changes to my wrapper and now use the StackExchange.Redis library rather than the previous BookSleeve. It all works now just fine. Thanks for the time and effort to help. (I am still relatively certain that even the most up-to-date BookSleeve version may suffer from a bug in terms of order preservation.)

Comment: @MattWolf I coverred that in the first line of my answer. Basically, if, as you suggest, there is a bug in BookSleeve with regards completion order, then it is very unlikely to be fixed: all future development is targeted at SE.Redis, not BookSleeve, as per the hyperlink. So: if you have the capacity to migrate, yes I say take a look at SE.Redis (I'm the author of both).

Comment: Just done (please see above post), thanks for your help and effort, it works just fine now.

Comment: @Matt note that actually there is a minor bug prior to .222 which means that the order isn't *quite* guaranteed. It is fixed from .222 onwards.

Comment: when do you anticipate this version to be up on Nuget? Thanks

Comment: @MattWolf guidance added here: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/PubSubOrder.md - nuget updating in about 2 minutes

Comment: "(I am still relatively certain that even the most up-to-date BookSleeve version may suffer from a bug in terms of order preservation.)" - I haven't seen any evidence for that, but I have no reason to disbelieve you. The problem is that subtle threading issues such as completion order of an inherently async process are generally **really** hard, and given the current state of SE.Redis vs BookSleeve, I can't find a compelling reason to open that particular can of worms.

Comment: Do you mind commenting on what the roadmap for StackExchange.Redis is? Do you anticipate this library to be maintained and updated in the foreseeable future? I am asking because I am also considering ServiceStack.Redis.Thanks

Comment: @MattWolf absolutely - it is now the core library we are actively using inside stackexchange / stackoverflow for talking to redis. The fact that we had to take the decision that the things we wanted to do in the future wouldn't all fit inside BookSleeve should be a positive sign that we actively want to continue and grow our use. If we were just quietly being passive, we would have kept with BookSleeve.